# SIMPLE question - trace() in Java?

Tags: java, android

Just started using Java (for Android, if that matters) and all I want is a write to the Console at runtime.  In AS3 it would be trace(), in c# it would be Console.Write()...what is it in Java?

I think this question is so basic/simple that I am having a hard time phrasing my question to Google; Stackoverflow to the rescue! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> System.out.print --> This will print without a final newline-character
>   System.out.println  --> This will print with a newline-character, but is the same as the above
>   System.out.printf --> This will accept format-specfiers, where the first argument is the mask and the other arguments are replacements.

http://sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/specification.htm

This will work when you are doing "Android Java", if you use Eclipse it will be shown in LogCat

> Log.d/w/e... --> Android

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`android.util.Log`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html). Also see the developer reference on [debugging](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/index.html) in general.